# Grub 2.04 install says it's successful but drops into the rescue shell

Tags: grub, uefi, bootloader, gpt, boot-partition

Our hardware is successfully running with UEFI/GRUB 2.02. The internal disk (/dev/sda) is GPT and the first partition starts at 1Mib, is 5Gb, and formatted as vfat. We are running Gentoo and using overlayfs. I need to update it to 2.04 so we can add Secure Boot.

I successfully used ebuild/emerge and updated GRUB. There are no errors during the install, but when the system reboots and runs GRUB it drops into the rescue shell with an "error: no such partition". If I copy all the files to their appropriate place in the 'real' /boot/grub, I get error: symbol `grub_file_filters` not found.

Prior to rebooting I've checked: - the disk partitions and they look correct - Dumped the first 4 LBA's of the disk and they appear to be a gpt partition table - efibootmgr -v displays what appears to be the correct info: \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI

The /dev/sda1/ mounted as /boot has the EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI file as well as the grub/x86_64-efi/* and grub/grub.cfg files.

After basic install:
The 'ls' command in the rescue shell gives (hd0) (hd1) (hd2) (hd3) (hd4) (hd5)
The internal boot drive is on (hd4).

After I copy all the relevant files from 'boot/boot.g1_n2/EFI|grub':
The 'ls' command in the rescue shell gives (hd0) (hd1) (hd2) (hd3) (hd4) (hd4,gpt3) (hd4,gpt2) (hd4,gpt1) (hd5)
The internal boot drive is still on (hd4)

We have a terrible, awkward debug environment that involves a minimal linux install environment and PXE booting every ISO. I feel like I've tried what I've found via google, but I'm sure I've missed something.

I've tried following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI along with various other things including answers on this site.

I'm not sure what else to try. Any other ideas?

Comment: I finally got grub updated. I was trying to use grub-2.04-r1 and grub-2.04-rc1. Both failed. I finally tried grub-2.04 and it was successful. I also had to unmount the overlays and run grub-install straight onto /dev/sda1.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer to your own question and flag it as a solution so it might help other people later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got grub updated. I was trying to use grub-2.04-r1 and grub-2.04-rc1. Both failed. I finally tried grub-2.04 and it was successful. I also had to unmount the overlays and run grub-install straight onto /dev/sda1.